# Window doesn't appear in Perl/Tk

Tags: perl, tk-toolkit, perltk

```
$mw=MainWindow->new(-title=>'Game of Life');
$frmitems=$mw->Frame;
$frmsettings=$mw->Frame;
$lab1=$frmsettings->Label(-text=>'Size of square:')->pack;
$hen=$frmsettings->Entry(-textvariable=>10);
$lab2=$frmsettings->Label(-text=>' x ');
$wen=$frmsettings->Entry(-textvariable=>10);
$hen->grid($lab2,$wen);
$ststr=$frmsettings->Label(-text=>"Current step: $step")->pack;
$frmitems->grid($frmsettings);
$mw->gridColumnconfigure(0, -pad => 10);
$mw->gridColumnconfigure(1, -pad => 10);
$mw->MainLoop;
```

This code should make a simple window. But nothing appears after MainLoop. If I use

```
$hen->pack($lab2,$wen);
```

instead of

```
$hen->grid($lab2,$wen);
```

window appears, but I need another geometry (like with grid). What's wrong?

ActivePerl 5.16 on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

$lab1 is using `pack`, but $hen, $lab2, and $wen are trying to use `grid` (all in the same frame).  Mixing geometry managers in a widget doesn't work.  From Mastering Perl/Tk:

> but if we start using pack, we should continue to use pack on all the
>   widgets contained directly in $mw. Don't switch to grid in the middle,
>   because the two geometry managers will get into a race condition: one
>   will create its layout, which affects the geometry calculations of the
>   other, which affects the layout of the first, causing it to recompute
>   its geometries, ad infinitum.

Changing $lab1 to use `grid` should fix that